# How do I train a neural network from many sets of data?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning

I have many sets of related data that I want to use to train a neural network. The data is from racing pigeons that fly a set distance. The inputs could be weight, age, size, wing span, sex, distance, time etc. sampled lets say every minute.
I am trying to predict the typical time a pigeon, given the inputs, would take in completing a race.
The input data would be normalised to improve the efficiency of the network.
A typical line of data may look like for weight, age, size, wing span, sex, distance, time would be
-1.34, -1.23, -0.49, 0.47, 0.97, -1, -1.44, -0.75
There would be many of these lines as the race progresses and at the end there would be a time result for each pigeon. Ie 3 hours 5 minutes.
I would then have a complete set of data for this race but obviously each race will be different so I need a way of training it for many races.
My question is, because each race is a discreet event what methods should I use to train the network. What I am confused about is this isn't a continuous stream of data that I can just let it get to work on. Should I train it with one set\race until it has learnt that and then move onto the next one etc or is there a methodology to use for this type of problem.

Thanks!

Comment: describe exactly what you are trying to achieve. In particular - how exactly each data "part" looks like and more important - what is your aim (what you try to predict/model)

Comment: I have expanded my question to include more detail and a typical line of data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have:

1. A set of races
2. For each race, you have a set of pigeons
3. For each pigeon within the race you have a series of values you record each minute.
4. For each pigeon within the race you also have his final time.
5. You want to predict what will be the final time for a pigeon given a series of values recorded so far in a live race.

If this is all correct, then I would observe the following:

1. For the purpose of this problem it would make sense to ignore whether two pigeons were flying in the same race or in two different races. Thus, the concept of a "race" can be dropped, and the input data can be now just thought of as a set of recorded flies by pigeons.
2. By nature, your data is time series. Regular feed forward networks are not good with time series. You need to use a recurrent network. Presently, the two kinds of recurrent networks that are often used in practice are LSTMs and GRUs.

Writing recurrent neural networks from scratch is not a good idea. Choose a framework (Keras, TensorFlow, Mxnet etc), find documentation on how to train an LSTM in that framework -- all of them have such tutorials -- and adjust it for your use case.

Comment: Many thanks for summarising my question in a much clearer way than I did. You have it exactly right. One thing I would ideally like to do was include the set of pigeons per race rather than individually because pigeons act differently when flying in sets. So one pigeon may race differently in one race with one set of pigeons compared to another race with another set of pigeons. I was hoping to capture that nuance as well. Is that possible?

Comment: @SpeedOfSpin: Remember to accept your favourite answer so that SO can properly archive your question.

Comment: @SpeedOfSpin, if you have significantly fewer pigeons than datapoints (i.e. if you have a lot of info about each pigeon), you can add info about other pigeons into the network. To do that, associate a vector of certain size with each pigeon (it is called embedding, and framework docs often have info on how to implmeent embeddings), and use some function of those embeddings (e.g. multiply each of them by the same matrix and add the results together) as the initial state of the recurrent network. Then train the embeddings together with the rest of the parameters.

Comment: Ok great thanks Ishamael. Thats giving me a great start. I will do some reading. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> (This was intended to be a comment, but became too long, so I put it as answer ;) )

There's an important thing to have in mind about feedforward neural networks trained by backpropagation: The backpropagation algorithm adjusts the weights by going through the complete set of data once and again, thus (hopefully) refining the results and finding a nice set of them.

After this process is finished, the weights are fixed, and you cannot include more information (that would adjust the weights only to the new data).

That all means, you either train with all races at once (as @Ishamael) suggested, or you train *a different NN for each race*.

Or you move to other types of networks and [learning algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning).

In the end, the question is *what do I want to do with the network after it is trained?*

Comment: Thanks Luis. That's my main problem really. Understanding how I train all the races at once.

Comment: From my experience, mixing categorical (discrete) with continuous variables as inputs can lead to the network overreacting to that value. To make myself clear: If there were 2 races for each birdy, and you code them like *0* and *1*, you can get a very different time (output) if you slighlty change that value.  Also, if there were a third race, how do you include it, if they are not(!) ordered?

Comment: I guess one idea could be (if that makes sense) to put the *number* of pigeons in that race... Or the relative social range of the pidgeon to the group. Something *more numerical*... If nothing of that sort makes sense, you can always ignore it and have *the abstracted flying behaviour* of each bird. But, again, it seems to me that this is an issue of experimental setup, rather than NN-stuff.